# Код работает на localhost, но не работает на хостинге

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '****.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,'session=1234567');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
$out=curl_exec($ch);
//$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($info['request_header']);
echo $out;
curl_close($ch);
```

Заливал код на 2 разных хостинга, нигде не авторизируется, но на localhostе все работает(request headerы одинаковы и на localhost`е, и на хостингах)

Comment: Так может сессия истекла? Или к IP привязана.

Comment: Сессия была валидна, после смены айпи продолжает функционировать.  Я только начал изучать php,  не могу определить где я ошибся. Кстате скрипт на питоне все делает как нужно, тоесть возвращает страницу для авторизированных пользователей

Comment: может на хосте отключено `allow_url_fopen` На бесплатных так это 99% случаев

Comment: Проверил, allow_url_fopen, везде включен

Answer (score 1):

При запуске скрипта необходимо сначала авторизироваться на форуме

```
$postdata = array(
    'login' => "логин",
    'password' => "пароль",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://dota2.ru/forum/login/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

При последующей работе со страницами форума просто используете сохраненную куки

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://dota2.ru/forum/forums/samoe-   obsuzhdaemoe.164/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Данная схема еще ни разу не подводила.

Comment: В вопрос добавил данные аккаунта, проверьте работоспособность ответа,  у меня не работает ни на локалхосте, ни на хостинге